# Connection Pooling per Tenant

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm stuck on an issue that is running a connection pool like AddDbContextPool by tenant by changing the database connection depending on which tenant is accessing, and that it becomes possible to reuse the same connections by tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Doing multi-tenant contexts is essentially a hack, relying on the fact that the context is scoped to the request. However, the whole point of pooling is to persist the underlying database connection *across* requests, so it's fundamentally incompatible with doing multi-tenant.

This methodology is old and out-dated now, anyways, though. ASP.NET Core is light-weight, self-contained, and configuration driven, making it highly suitable to running multiple instances, rather than just one instance trying to cover every possible scenario. In other words, you can deploy the same exact application multiple times, and simply switch out things like the connection string via config for each deployment, making multi-tenant unnecessary: every tenant can and should just have their own instance. That's far more secure anyways. As an enterprise customer, myself, I would *never* go with a service that co-located their customers in one instance. That's just a recipe for having your data leaked or hacked.